# install works but unable to run the application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, clickonce

This is a Windows 7 machine with Service Pack 1, and I published a C# WPF application using x86 target platform configuration since it also needs to be installed on XP machines.

The problem I'm dealing with is becoming a nuisance. The application runs fine in Visual Studio 2008 debug mode. After running the setup executable generated from publishing, the installation completes successfully (or at least appears that way), but when it attempts to open, I get the `Application cannot be started. Contact the application vendor.` message box.

Here is the Error Summary section of the log file:

```
ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of http://ServerPath/MyApplication_Install/Release/x86/MyApplication.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

And the Error Details section:

```
ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [9/12/2012 8:15:42 AM] System.ArgumentException
    - Value does not fall within the expected range.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.CorLaunchApplication(UInt32 hostType, String applicationFullName, Int32 manifestPathsCount, String[] manifestPaths, Int32 activationDataCount, String[] activationData, PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
        at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.Activate(DefinitionAppId appId, AssemblyManifest appManifest, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

There are other ClickOnce questions on here that deal with `Microsoft.Vbe.Interop, Version=14.0.0.0` - that does appear in this log file under the `OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS` section, but it doesn't say the assembly needs to be installed in the Global Assembly Cache.

```
* [9/12/2012 8:45:19 AM] : Detecting dependent assembly Microsoft.Vbe.Interop, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C, processorArchitecture=msil using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=msil.
* [9/12/2012 8:45:19 AM] : Detecting dependent assembly Microsoft.Vbe.Interop, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C using Microsoft.Vbe.Interop, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c.
```

Do I need to remove leftover files/folders from previous installations? That's my gut feeling, but I don't know where to look inside the AppData/Local/Temp or Windows/System32 folders.

**Edit**

I did some deep digging and found the executable for my application here:

`C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\A30V87AA.25Q\PQ06CCDW.CYM\wpfb..tion_41f7e986af356c0c_0004.0004_b15da840f06645a3\MyApplication.exe`

It loaded up without any errors. And to confirm this was from the installation, not my source code, I did an uninstall in Control Panel, checked that directory and all the files were gone.

After re-installing from setup.exe, a different set of jibberish folder directories were made, but I was still able to run the application.

So why does the `Application cannot be started. Contact the application vendor.` message pop up after installation, even though there is a working copy deep inside the `AppData` directory?

**Edit #2**

As suggested by `jvanh1`, I ran as an administrator to see if that made any difference.  Unfortunately it didn't.

I was forced to checkout the latest tagged version and do some manual copy/pasting - the subsequent publish actually worked. The more important issue here is that we never have used branching before in our version control (at least not for this application), so I convinced my manager to let me give it a shot.

I will continue to investigate what caused this annoying ClickOnce publish problem in the first place - my guess is different sets of references in the tagged version vs. my working copy.

Comment: Do you reference an assembly from the GAC? If yes, do you Copy Local the assembly? You depend on libraries not directly referenced by your project?

Comment: @Scoregraphic I checked the referenced assemblies and changed the Copy Local value to True for all of them except ones starting with `System`. However, when I republished, this time the message box said `An error has occurred writing to the hard disk. Check if there is enough available space on the disk. Contact the application vendor.`

Comment: I undid those changed to make sure I don't mess anything else up

Comment: The difference my come from a different working directory. Are you checking some paths (the relative way) inside your application? I guess ClickOnce deployment process has a working directory set to System32 or similar. When starting manually, the working directory is your application folder. You may have to set the working directory to your main assembly file location.

Comment: @Scoregraphic Is there a difference between default working directories in Windows XP and Windows 7? This is the first time trying to publish from a Windows 7 machine. The working directory value under Project Settings -> Debug has always been left blank and no problems ever arose from that.

Comment: Silly question, have you tried running it as administrator?

Comment: Never thought of trying that but I'll see what happens tomorrow around 8 AM EST when I'm back in the office.

Comment: That didn't appear to do the job

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a very similar issue, it turns out one of the reference dll was moved but the hintpath wasn't updated. VS didn't warn me, instead it automatically referenced the GAC copy, causing a prerequisite change. I fixed the issue by replacing the GAC reference with local dll reference.